# How does Keras calculate validation metrics when using model.fit()?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

How does keras calculate validation metrics when using `model.fit()`? I found an answer [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426#issuecomment-397485072), but I'm still confused by the following behaviour.

Following a simple tensorflow tutorial:

```py
# define model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,), name='digits')
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='predictions', activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# compile model
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[
        tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy"),
        tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(name="cross")
    ],
)

# get training data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
y_test = y_test.astype('float32')

x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).repeat().batch(64)

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(64)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(64)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=1000, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

The output is:

```sh
Epoch 1/3
1000/1000 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: 0.8685 - accuracy: 0.7120 - cross: 0.8685 - val_loss: 0.3464 - val_accuracy: 0.9086 - val_cross: 0.3472
Epoch 2/3
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3269 - accuracy: 0.9082 - cross: 0.3269 - val_loss: 0.2587 - val_accuracy: 0.9298 - val_cross: 0.2598
Epoch 3/3
1000/1000 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2800 - accuracy: 0.9203 - cross: 0.2800 - val_loss: 0.2449 - val_accuracy: 0.9308 - val_cross: 0.2460
```

In this example, I set `learning_rate=1` so that the loss value should equal to cross entropy. What bothers me is that the `val_loss` and `val_cross` don't match exactly, but they really should! Training loss and training cross entropy does match each other.

I'm guessing that `val_loss`, which is automatically calculated (you don't need to pass a metric for this), is the average over all validation batches, whereas `cross` is the value for the last batch in validation set, because it is a metric added by myself. Does anyone have an explanation?

Some documentation would really be helpful, especially for such a high level function like `model.fit`. There are so many things happening under the hood with a single function call, I think detailed documentation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That is true, according to the documentation on Tensorflow, while used as [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) it resets its states (calls the `reset_states()` function) after each epoch/*step*, and when used as [loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy), it does not reset, so the result is based on the average of all batches.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but perhaps you misunderstood my question. I'm confused by these two values: `val_loss` and 'val_cross', they are both metrics in the validation stage, so they should have same behaviour regarding resets. Also, I believe they should be equal to each other, because in my example cross entropy is loss. Note that training loss is exactly the same as training cross entropy.

Comment: Nope. `val_loss` is `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` while `val_cross` is `tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()`. A `loss` function is optimized by your model during training, i.e., the model tries to minimize it as much as possible by changing its weights/parameters. However, a `metric` is a function for you to check the performance of your model, the model does not optimize, i.e, does not change its parameters based on it. Hence, `val_cross` which is a metric function resets its states at each step, but '`val_loss` accumulates it throughout all the batches.

Comment: How can I confirm which object type is `val_loss`? I got this value back automatically when using model.fit() so I'm not sure what it is. I know the difference between loss and metric, but `val_loss` should not be used to optimize your model, it is meant to be a metirc to tell you what your validation loss is at the current training stage.

Comment: Yes, I did not say val_loss is used for optimization. I said Loss function is used for optimization. You can confirm which is which by their name. Val_cross is your metric and that’s how you named it. Val_loss automatically named that way and no matter what loss function you use, if you have validation data, it will be there. For example if you change your loss function to let’s say ‘mse’ (not that it’s suitable here) it will still name it val_loss.